# What is the difference between spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client, spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 and spring-security-oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud

I am developing a client application for client_credentials grant type flow in OAUTH2.

I am not able to decide on which dependency to use in my project for this purpose among the following.

1. spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client
2. spring-cloud-starter-oauth2
3. spring-security-oauth2

I referred this [documentation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix#client-support) from spring-projects in which under client-support section it had a table describing the available options. But I am not able to understand which column is referring to which of the above dependencies.

I want to configure a `WebClient` or `RestTemplate` which retrieves the OAUTH2 token from the auth-server automatically before accessing a resource-server.

Please guide me in choosing the right artifact for my project.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot you should choose `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client`.
This includes Spring Security's OAuth 2.0 Client support and provides Spring Boot auto-configuration to set up OAuth2/Open ID Connect clients.
You can read about how to configure client in the Spring Boot [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.security.oauth2.client).
You can also find additional details in the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html).

If you are not using Spring Boot then you should choose `org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client`. This also provides Spring Security's latest OAuth 2.0 Client support, but does not include the Spring Boot auto-configuration.
The corresponding documentation is also the Spring Security [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/index.html).

The third dependency you mentioned `org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2` should not be used because it is part of the [legacy Spring Security OAuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth) project, which is now deprecated.
The functionality that this library provided has now been moved into Spring Security.
That is what the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Features-Matrix#client-support) describes, the migration from the legacy project to the latest Spring Security support.

You should not use the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-oauth2` at this time, because it relies on the legacy OAuth support.
This is likely to change in the future, as the Spring Cloud team updates to the latest Spring Security support.