# SpringBoot + AWS Cognito configuration, I need some clarification

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to start a new simple project with SpringBoot using AWS Cognito for authentication/authorization

Following some guide on web i found some different configuration, for example:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-cognito
- https://wilkom2009.hashnode.dev/how-to-secure-spring-boot-rest-api-endpoints-with-amazon-cognito

In the Baeldung is used only the spring module **spring-security-oauth2-jose** while in the second guide use only **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server** and he configures the resource-server. Both the configuration allow the user to login and access to application.

I can't figure out the difference between this 2 configuration and when I should use one instead of another.
In other guide i saw use both together.

Thanks to all

I'm trying to create a simple angular single page application.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Baeldung article looks like it is just using Spring and not Spring Boot. So they wouldn't use **spring-boot-starter** modules.

If you are using Spring Boot you should be able use the **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server** and follow the second guide.

**spring-security-oauth2-jose** is actually a dependency of **spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server** and is used by it under the hood.

Related post about spring-boot-starter vs spring modules:
[What is the difference between spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client, spring-cloud-starter-oauth2 and spring-security-oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081479/what-is-the-difference-between-spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client-spring-cloud-s)

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, a 3rd solution: the 2nd of [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) has a profile for Cognito (see the properties file). It is shorter / simpler than what you referenced and enables Role Based Access Control (using Cognito roles, not just the default scope claim)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/us-west-2_change-me
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=cognito:groups,scp
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/your-api-path
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/what,/should/be,/accessible,/to,/anonymous
```

Also, be sure to use a [certified OpenID lib](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) on client side. My favorite for Angular is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client).